# What's the difference between these two code for find the max depth of a binary tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree

I'm working on this leetcode problem:

https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/

Given a binary tree, find its maximum depth.

The maximum depth is the number of nodes along the longest path from the root node down to the farthest leaf node.

Working Code:

```
public class Solution {
    public int maxDepth(TreeNode root) {

        if(root == null)
            return 0;

        int left = maxDepth(root.left);
        int right = maxDepth(root.right);

        if(left > right)
            return left + 1;
        else
            return right + 1;
    }
}
```

---

Non-working Code:

```
public class Solution {
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
    public int maxDepth(TreeNode root) {

        if(root == null)
            return 0;

        left = maxDepth(root.left);
        right = maxDepth(root.right);

        if(left > right)
            return left + 1;
        else
            return right + 1;
    }
}
```

Could someone explain why one doesn't work?  Recursion hurts my head.

Comment: *"Could someone explain why they both don't work?"* You've said the first one *does* work.

Comment: Wait, it says theres a working code and not working code and then ask why they both don't work. A little confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, which you've said works, `left` and `right` are *local variables* within `maxDepth`, and so *each call* to `maxDepth` has its own private copy of them that other calls to `maxDepth` cannot change.

In the second example, `left` and `right` are instance fields, and so all calls to `maxDepth` on that instance will *share* them. Consequently, when `maxDepth` calls itsself, it overwrites the values in `left` and `right` from any containing call. E.g., here:

```
left = maxDepth(root.left);
right = maxDepth(root.right);
```

...the first call returns a value for `left`, which is then *overwritten* by the second call, because the second call also does `left = maxDepth(root.left);`. Additionally, if you end up recursing further (as you probably will), both `left` *and* `right` are overwritten.